# The argument type 'Future<Translation>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I am using translator library in flutter `import 'package:translator/translator.dart';`

I'm trying to add this translation in my widget

```
child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      translator.translate('Help', to :"it"),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
```

But i get the convertion error i searched through several articles but could not find a fix fo it

The future is inside the text and it cant be converted

Comment: Wrap the `Text ` widget into `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @dm_tr `child: ListTile(
                    title: FutureBuilder(
                      Text(
                        translator.translate('Help', to: Language.inUseLang.toString() ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    ),` i wrapped it but still the same